# Y axis depth sorting in SDL2

Tags: rendering, sdl, depth-buffer, yaxis

I've been using SDL for my game but rendering order as always been a problem. When you draw something in SDL, it gets drawn over what was drawn before it. Which means, if I draw a character at 10 in the Y coordinate, and I draw a character at 5 in the Y coordinate, the one at 5 appears above the one at 10, even though it should be the other way around.

To demonstrate the problem.

[image]

This is what it should be like. The one with lower Y axis value should appear behind no matter which one I draw first.

[image]

In 3D, things don't need to be rendered in a specific order, things are drawn behind other things according to the Z buffer. I want SDL to behave the same way, but on the Y axis. How?

Comment: You need to keep a list of objects and sort it before rendering.

Comment: @solarc I know I can do that but it creates more problem. I need to use depth buffering like 3d does.

Comment: @aganm there is no such functionality in SDL, it disables depth buffer and never uses it. Even if there were, blending don't work like that in 3d either, so with transparency you usually still have to sort and render far-to-near.